# Zend_translate class not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, translate

I simply want to start using the Zend_translate

```
  $translate = new Zend_Translate('array',array(),'en_EN');

$fi = array(
    'Hello World' => 'Hei Maailma'
);

$translate->addTranslation($fi,'fi_FI');
$translate->setLocale('fi_FI');
echo $translate->_('Hello World');
```

on this I get `Class 'Zend_Translate' not found

Of course I need to install something first...BUT there is nowhere said what I should set and how to install. The Zend documentation does not say how to install these stuff and I could not find it on internet, please help

Comment: what version of Zend framework are you using?

Comment: I installed it from composer create-project -s dev zendframework/skeleton-application, should be zend 3

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you need to be using namespaces. as shown in some of the samples here: https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/modules/

Comment: Start with `use Zend\Translate;` at the top of your file and then you can use `new Translate` I believe. As long as you have the autoloader working.

Comment: there is no such class at all, I probably have to install something

Comment: I put it and as I said...it is still the same. there is no such class anywhere

Comment: Hm. I am not sure. I'm sorry. I believe it usually comes all bundled together though. But maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope - it's not bundled. Also - the tutorial or sample code you have is not using ZF3, but ZF1. You can already tell from the underscore class name (Zend_Translate).

In ZF3 you have to install the modules:

`composer require zendframework/zend-i18n`
and optionally (if you use the MVC compoments)
`composer require zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n`

The 2 tutorials / docs relevant for i18n can be found here

https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/i18n/

https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-i18n/translation

Comment: This is what I get after installation  Method Zend\View\Helper\HeadTitle::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Zend\I18n\Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException: Zend\I18n\Translator component requires the intl PHP extension

Comment: yeah, you have to enable/install the intl php extension.

Comment: I figured, I was using php 7 and it seems that this extension is in php 5 only, however i switched my project to php 5 and enabled the extension but the error is still there

Comment: ah ... no need. its available for php7 as well. You just have to include the version e.g. `sudo apt-get install php7.1-intl` and enable it `phpenmod intl` ... also reload/restart the webserver after that e.g. `service nginx reload`